# How to add IB constraints programmatically only for one specific ViewController?

Tags: iphone, constraints, xcode4.5, uistoryboard

I am creating an iPhone app. The app has been developed to fit on the 4 inch screen. Now I have to add support for the 3.5 inch screen. I have some views that are automatically adapting such as `UITableViews`. However, I also have a view that contains a lot of objects from Interface Builder.

With this piece of code I check if the screen is 3.5 or 4 inches:

```
if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    if(result.height == 480)
    {
        // iPhone Classic
        NSLog(@"iPhone with 3.5 Inch screen");
    }
    if(result.height == 568)
    {
        // iPhone 5
        NSLog(@"iPhone with 4 Inch screen");
    }
}
```

Can I add the IB constraints from the storyboard **for this specific ViewController** in this code check? What is the easiest way to create these constraints programmatically?

---

Edit:
What I want to achieve:

- Get my properties
- Deactivate autoLayout of this particular ViewController in Storyboard
- Manually add constratins in the check above.

Here is a list of my defined properties in my ViewControllers .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger selectedIndex;
@property (nonatomic, retain) AbstractActionSheetPicker *actionSheetPicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *workerField;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dateField;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *workers;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate *selectedDate;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *cutSwitcher;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *colorSwitcher;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UISwitch *waveSwitcher;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL internetActive;
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hostActive;
```

Comment: do you mean the object constraints in XIB?

Comment: Yes the ones that can also be set in IB for objects.

Comment: maybe you must write a code directly in the IB. Instead why don't copy the xib e call the view for each xib?

Answer (score 0):

Set CGRect for all objects in your Xib file. Set One version for iPhone 4 and another for iPhone 5.

```
        CGSize result = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        CGRect master;
        if(result.height == 480)
        {
            // iPhone Classic
            NSLog(@"iPhone with 3.5 Inch screen");
            CGRect classic = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
            master = classic;
        }
        if(result.height == 568)
        {
            // iPhone 5
            NSLog(@"iPhone with 4 Inch screen");
            CGRect iPhone5 = CGRectMake(0,0,0,0);
            master = iPhone5;
        }

someView.frame = master;
```

EDIT:

First, I don't think you can disable auto-layout for a specific viewController. Second, if you replace the rect logic in my answer above with method logic, it should still work the same. Make two methods, one for each view, and add them in the if (result.height ==). Whether you want to do this directly in the viewController or a singleton class is up to you.

Comment: Thank you. I know how to get the screen size and change it accordingly. But I want to use the bigger screen differently than the smaller screen. Therefore they are not the same.